# RPI 2 vs RPI B SD compatibility issue

Tags: raspbian, boot, sd-card

I've been using a Raspbian image with some preinstalled software for digital signage on a RPI B+ and RPI 2 so far. I've been using a common 16Gb SD card, and decided to move to 2Gb industrial grade ATP card. 
The image fits perfectly well with Win32 disk imager (as usual), but RPI 2 won't boot whereas RPI B boots well.

Unfortunately, ATP is not in the SD compatibility list as a manufacturer, and I wasn't able to find any additional info.

So, something changed between RPI B+ and RPI 2 regarding SD cards usability?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "won't boot"?  Does the green led come on at all?  If so and it blinks, how many times does it blink?  Have you tried this with a display attached?  What does it show?

Comment: It only blinks once than goes off. I have tried to boot with a screen plugged, no signal received at any atime

Comment: One blink is [undocumented](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern); two blinks would be normal, 3+ would be it's reading the SD card but doesn't like what's on it.  As far as I've noticed no blinks (i.e., red light only) means no SD card, or an SD card without a proper MBR.  So perhaps, as you say, it just cannot read it correctly.

Comment: Strange. I've tested once again, green LED goes on as soon as I power it on, than it goes off after 1 second, and never switches on again. Red light stays lit on permanently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the image contains /boot/kernel7.img for the Pi 2 to boot.  Older images, such as the one I got with my Pi 2, may not come with it.

The older Pis, models A, A+, B, B+ use ARM v6 processors, sometimes referred to as armel.  They use the /boot/kernel.img kernel.

The Pi 2 uses an ARM v7 processor, sometimes referred to as armhf.  They use the /boot/kernel7.img kernel.

If the OS image you're trying to boot does not contain kernel7.img then it simply will not boot on a Pi 2, but will be fine on the older models.  You need to obtain a newer OS image that is compatible with Pi 2, or find a way of installing a Pi 2 compatible kernel into the older image.

Comment: Yes, but the same image works on this RPI 2 when cloned to a basic 16Gb SD card

Comment: Yes, it actually contains kernel.img, but not kernel7.img

Comment: I've tested 2 other SD cards. Another ATP, 4Gb industrial grade, and a 4Gb industrial grade InnoDisk

Comment: What happens if you format the card and put a decent operating system on instead of something Linux based?  For example a RiscOS image.  I've had a number of card issues which have had to be filed under "Linux - don't do it."