# ptxdist and Rpi

Tags: image

I am trying to create an image for raspberry using ptxdist, but I can not create an image that works.

I followed the tutorial "OSELAS.BSP-Pengutronix-Generic-arm-Quickstart.pdf"

Step:

- Compile and install 2014.05.0.
- Donwload toolchain.
- Download OSELAS.BSP-Pengutronix-Generic-2014.07.0
- Download platform-pengutronix-raspberrypi
- ptxdist migrate (version plarform is ptxdist 2014.05.0)
- ptxdist go
- ptxdist image

The image is successfully created, copy it to a card but don't work only  black screen.

ptxdist someone previously used and has managed to create a functional image?

System:

- OSELAS.BSP-Pengutronix-Generic-2014.07.0

  - platform-pengutronix-raspberrypi
  - Toolchain :OSELAS.Toolchain-2013.12.0-arm-1136jfs-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.2-glibc-2.18-binutils-2.24-kernel-3.12-sanitized
- ptxdist-2014.05.0
- Ubuntu 14.04
- Raspberry Pi model B.

Comment: The green light on the pi probably flashes steadily a fixed number of times  when you try to boot.  **How many?**

Comment: the green light don't flashes. When starting the green light is lights but then turns off.

Comment: I think it's not finding anything on the card.  Two flashes is normal and would indicate a kernel was booted.  [3 or more flashes](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern) indicates some of `start.elf` or the kernel failed to load.  No green light ever will happen if there is no SD card or the SD card does not have an MBR.  So your problem could be that there's [something about the card it doesn't like](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28849/rpi-2-vs-rpi-b-sd-compatibility-issue).

Comment: ...If you have used that card in a pi before and it was okay with a different image, then obviously this image is screwed up in a very fundamental way.  Have you tried examining the partitions in another machine?

Comment: there are 2 partitions: .
*  bootcode.bin
* cmdline.txt
*  config.txt
*  fixup_cd.dat
* fixup.dat
*  fixup_x.dat
*  kernel.img
*  start_cd.elf
* start.elf
* start_x.elf
other with the system (bin,etc,home...)

Comment: You should compare the `*.elf` files in the first partition to the stuff on a card that works.  That seems the most likely place for it to be stuck.

Comment: Or `bootcode.bin`, which gets no mention in the led-flashes-troubleshooting thing.  There's a description of the [process here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=5170).  You could in fact just copy the `bootcode.bin` and `*.elf` stuff from a card that works and see what happens with that.  You do need to keep your kernel though.

Comment: If copy this files. the Rpi start and i can access via telnet.

Comment: So you are saying it works with the other `start.elf`, etc.?  Well, that sounds like a solution.  See if you can put that into an answer yourself -- the interface here might say you have to wait 24 hours or something, if so let me know and I'll do it.  Then this question is resolved.

Comment: sounds like a temporal solution but now the question is: why the files are not generated correctly? Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: It's a permanent solution for you ;)  As to why there's this issue, you [might have to ask them](http://www.ptxdist.org/mailinglists/index_en.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating the BSP all by yourself you can also try the DistroKit BSP by pengutronix. Upstream Git repository is at http://git.pengutronix.de/?p=DistroKit.git;a=summary and you can already get a lot of helpful inspiration. However when trying this by myself last year I got no functional image with the master tree of those repositories, some changes must be made to get it running.

I did that last year but didn't manage to get my patches upstream yet. However if you want to quickly have a running image to start playing with you could have a look at the *migrate* branches of my forks on my personal GitHub account.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ready ptxdist project at https://gitlab.com/k6devel/ptxdist-raspberry-pi which is currently a little more recent than what comes from pengutronix.